# Change a single value of a textbox Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, modifier

I want to change only one value of an input, example: in the input income "xy" I want to change is only "and" Suppose a new value is "p", and "x" leave. The end result should be "xp".

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/previo/thump_2265651input.png
http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/previo/thump_2265653input2.png

```
<input type="text"id="txtChar1" onkeypress="isNumberKey();">

function isNumberKey()
{
  var text = document.getElementById(txtChar1).value;

  if (text[1] >= 0)
  {
    text[1].write("p");
    text[1].value ="p";
    text.charAt(1).value = "p";
    text[1].innerHTML = "p";
    text[1] = "p";
  }
}
```

Forget clarify the options that exist in this condition are those that probe and did not walk any.

Comment: shouldn´t you use `text[0]` for all this? Also, what is your error?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. Your description is unclear, but the best I can tell is that you want to reverse the order of the characters.

```
function isNumberKey()
{
  var el = document.getElementById("txtChar1");
  el.value = el.value.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

The `.split("")` converts the string into an Array of its characters. Then `.reverse()` reverses the order of those Array members and `.join("")` joins the members back into a string.

---

Another approach would be to pass `this` to the function, since that's the one getting updated.

```
<input type="text"id="txtChar1" onkeypress="isNumberKey(this);">
```

---

```
function isNumberKey(el)
{
  el.value = el.value.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

---

I won't go into detail about what was wrong with your code, because I think you were just throwing together a bunch of arbitrary bits of code in the hope that it would work. Needless to say, it's almost all wrong.

Comment: I think this isn't what OP wants (not sure since the question is so unclear). But +1 for "*Strings are immutable*".

Comment: @Oriol: Yeah, I'm not sure. The description makes almost no sense to me. I figure at least getting rid of all that wrong code is a good first step. :-)

Comment: Sorry, the input want to change the "Y" in the "P": http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/previo/thump_2265651input.png  http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/previo/thump_2265653input2.png

Comment: @FabricioNahuelRori: `el.value = el.value.replace("y", "p");`

Comment: or if you need to replace several, use a global regular expression. `el.value = el.value.replace(/y/g, "p");`

Comment: el.value.replace ("y", "p"); .... Works but the value of the input is not updated looks the same, only seen that was modified in alert (el)

Comment: @FabricioNahuelRori: Did you have the `el.value = ` part first like I typed in my comment above? Or did you do `el = ` instead? I think you may need to read some beginner's materials. These are all introductory concepts.

Comment: Uh recently saw, now eh tested and is right, andubo. Thanks a lot